# Does JSON Patch Operation support creation of new key,an array, in a JSON Object?

Tags: http, http-verbs, http-patch

I am trying to **add new array key in JSON object** but it is not adding a new element.

Below this `usedReference` is not present in the JSON object. I want to create this array Element `usedReference` without updating the JSON object.

```json
{
    "op": "add",
    "path": "/usedReference/-",
    "value": {
        "reference": "Aravind"
    }
}
```